# Spray-Test gzip decode

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json, spray-client, spray-test

I try write test for spray

```
class FullTestKitExampleSpec extends Specification with Specs2RouteTest with UserController with HttpService {
  def actorRefFactory = system

  "The service" should {

    "return a greeting for GET requests to the root path" in {
      Get("/user") ~> `Accept-Encoding`(gzip) ~> userRoute ~> check {
        val responsex = response
        responseAs[String] must contain("Test1")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have follow router

```
trait UserController extends HttpService with Json4sSupport with CORSSupport{
  override implicit def json4sFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats

  val userRoute = {
    cors {
      compressResponse(Gzip) {
        path("user") {
          get {
            complete {
              "Test1"
            }
          } ~
            post {
              entity(as[UserRegister]) { person =>
                complete {
                  println(person.name)
                  person.name
                }
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I use GZIP compression for response, but

> > Could not unmarshal response to type 'java.lang.String' for `responseAs` assertion: MalformedContent(unknown token 
> >     Near: ,Some(org.json4s.ParserUtil$ParseException: unknown token 
> >     Near: ))

How to set autodecode GZIP HttpResponse to String?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include a `decode(Gzip)` in your pipeline:

```
import spray.httpx.encoding.Gzip
import spray.httpx.ResponseTransformation

class MySprayRouteSpec extends FlatSpec
    with ShouldMatchers
    with ResponseTransformation
    with ScalatestRouteTest
    {
        Get("/") ~> mapHttpResponse(decode(Gzip))(userRoute) ~> check{
              response.status should equal(OK)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Error:(18, 65) not found: value decode
    Get("/user") ~> `Accept-Encoding`(identity) ~> userRoute ~> decode(Gzip)  ~> check {

Comment: Mix in `ResponseTransformation`, i.e. `class FullTestKitExampleSpec extends ResponseTransformation with ...`

Comment: Error:(19, 71) type mismatch;
 found   : FullTestKitExampleSpec.this.ResponseTransformer
    (which expands to)  spray.http.HttpResponse => spray.http.HttpResponse required:

Comment: Get("/user") ~> userRoute ~> decode(Gzip) ~> check {

Comment: I too don't know what required... Now i wont understand how to work pipelines.

Comment: No I mean, what does the error message say is required? You've cut it off just before the important part

Comment: `decode(Gzip)` is an `HttpResponse => HttpResponse` whereas the tilde function transforms a `RouteResult` object. Not sure what the nice way to write this is but I found I could get it to work by swapping out the route for `mapHttpResponse(decode(Gzip))(userRoute)`, from spray.routing.BasicDirectives.

Comment: Thanks William, your comment helped me. Also asking myself if there is an nicer solution